# Setting the setPreviewDisplayof the camera with the mHolder of SurfaceView in a separate thread?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have created separate thread to open the camera for preview with setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer. However, how do I set the  of the camera with the mHolder of SurfaceView? The Handler has to pass it as a message to the mThread?

```
package com.example.cameraactivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Button;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    private CameraHandlerThread mThread = null;

    private static class CameraHandlerThread extends HandlerThread implements PreviewCallback{
        private static final String TAG = "CameraHandlerThread";
        Handler mHandler = null;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private float framerate = 0;
        int i = 0, t = 0;
        long now, oldnow, count = 0;
        private int preview_width = 640, preview_height = 320;
        private int bitsPerPixel = 8;
        private int bufSize = preview_width * preview_height * bitsPerPixel/ 8;
        static final private int NUM_CAMERA_PREVIEW_BUFFERS = 2;

        CameraHandlerThread() {
            super("CameraHandlerThread");
            start();
            mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
        }

        synchronized void notifyCameraOpened() {
            notify();
        }

        void openCamera() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getCameraInstance();
                    notifyCameraOpened();
                }
            });
            try {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "wait was interrupted");
            }
        }

        private void getCameraInstance(){
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open(1);
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to open front camera");
            }
            setParameters();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CAMERA_PREVIEW_BUFFERS; i++) {
                byte [] cameraBuffer = new byte[bufSize];
                mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(cameraBuffer);
            }
            mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
            //mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        }

        private void setParameters(){
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            //params.setPreviewSize(640, 320);
            params.setPreviewFpsRange(150000, 150000);
            params.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
            params.setAutoExposureLock(true);
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }       

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            i++;
            now = System.nanoTime()/1000;
            t = (int)( now - oldnow);
            framerate = (int) (1000000/t);
            oldnow = now;
            Log.i(TAG, "Framerate: " + framerate);
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
        }

        void startPreview() {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

        void stopPreview() {
            mCamera.stopPreview();          
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        if (mThread == null) {
            mThread = new CameraHandlerThread();
        }

        synchronized (mThread) {
            mThread.openCamera();
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        synchronized (mThread) {
            mThread.startPreview();
        }
    }

    private void stopPreview() {
        synchronized (mThread) {
            mThread.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    public CameraPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //mCamera = camera;

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        //mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        Log.i(TAG, "init");
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            openCamera();
            startPreview();
            Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        stopPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          return;
        }

        try {
            stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
        }

        try {
            startPreview();
            Log.i(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want to limit your interactions with Camera to a single thread.  You should be able to wrap accesses from multiple threads with explicit mutex synchronization, but it's usually simpler to do everything on one.  If the camera handling and your surface callbacks run on different threads, it's probably best to pass the SurfaceHolder through a message to a Handler.

[Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) demonstrates a couple of different approaches.  In "Show + capture camera", the camera is handled on the UI thread.  In "Texture from camera", it's handled on the renderer thread.  See the notes near the top of each activity class for additional info.

Things can get complicated in a hurry when you try to manage the Camera object so that it is handled correctly with regard to the lifecycles of the app (pause/resume) and surface (created/destroyed), which aren't as tightly coupled as one might hope.  Some details about that can be found [here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) (also referenced from the comments in Grafika).